# Split a linestring

Tags: r, sf

I have a series of connected linestrings in `sf` that are grouped by a factor ("group"). For each linestring I have a single intersecting point ("state"). I'd like to split each linestring by group so that the linestring unto the point is coded as state = 0, and the linestring after the point is coded as state = 1.

Example code below:(where green = startpoint, red = endpoint, and the open circle is the intersecting node along each line):

[image]

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

path <- st_as_sf(data.frame(X = c(145.1, 145.2, 145.2, 145.3, 145.6, 145.65), 
                            Y = c(-16.1, -16.2, -16.25, -16.3, -16.4, -16.45), 
                            group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B")), 
             coords = c('X', 'Y'), crs = 20353) %>% 
                group_by(group) %>%
                summarise(do_union = F) %>% 
                st_cast('LINESTRING') %>%
                mutate(group=as.factor(group))

start_points <- path %>% st_line_sample(sample=0) %>% st_as_sf() %>% mutate(group=c("A","B"))
end_points <- path %>% st_line_sample(sample=1) %>% st_as_sf() %>% mutate(group=c("A","B"))
  
nodes <- st_line_sample(path, 1, sample=c(0.5)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mutate(group=as.factor(c("A","B"))) %>%
  mutate(state=as.factor("1"))

ggplot() + theme_bw() + facet_wrap(~group) +
  geom_sf(data=path, linetype="dotted") +
  geom_sf(data=start_points, color="green") +
  geom_sf(data=end_points, color="red") +
  geom_sf(data=nodes, color="black", shape=1)
```

I've tried using `str_split` to split the linestring in each group by the node and `st_join` approach:

```
st_split(path, nodes) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>% 
  st_join(., nodes, left=TRUE)
```

but I'm missing something, as there's duplicate groups (group.x and group.y):

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 145.1 ymin: -16.45 xmax: 145.65 ymax: -16.1
Projected CRS: AGD84 / AMG zone 53
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  group.x                                  geometry group.y state
 <fct>                            <LINESTRING [m]> <fct>   <fct>
 A        (145.1 -16.1, 145.2 -16.2, 145.2 -16.25) NA      NA   
 B       (145.3 -16.3, 145.6 -16.4, 145.65 -16.45) NA      NA
```

The result I'd like here is four line strings where each group is split into before (state=0) and after (state=1) the intersecting point, something like this::

```
  group state geometry
     A     0      ...
     A     1      ...
     B     0      ...
     B     1      ...
```

How can I solve this one using sf() in R?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in R, but the operation you are looking for is St_Union whith the group by and then you will have to decide what to do with the attribute ...

Comment: I'm not getting an `st_split` function from `sf`, so could you edit your Q and show where this comes from?

Comment: You're also going to have trouble splitting the paths at those nodes, since the nodes aren't precisely on the paths (`st_distance(paths, nodes)` shows distance of 1e-15, which means `st_intersects` is false which means splitting wont work).